# when updating a table says im changing values inside the trigger when im not

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

This trigger is supposed to stop if a interval between two dates are overlaping.
When i try to update a  table i get this error where says its in mutation i can't read it or modify, but i don't understand where.

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE1fy.png)

The code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trgepocasnaosobrepostas BEFORE
    UPDATE OR INSERT ON epoca
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    CURSOR c IS
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        epoca;

    cr_epoca c%rowtype;
    ex_data_sobreposta EXCEPTION;
    ex_data_null EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    OPEN c;
    IF inserting THEN
        IF ( :new.data_fim IS NULL ) THEN
            RAISE ex_data_null;
        END IF;
        FETCH c INTO cr_epoca;
        IF ( ( :new.data_ini BETWEEN cr_epoca.data_ini AND cr_epoca.data_fim ) OR ( :new.data_fim BETWEEN cr_epoca.data_ini AND cr_epoca
        .data_fim ) ) THEN
            RAISE ex_data_sobreposta;
        END IF;

    END IF;

    CLOSE c;
    IF updating THEN
        IF ( ( :new.data_ini BETWEEN :old.data_ini AND :old.data_fim ) OR ( :new.data_fim BETWEEN :old.data_ini AND :old.data_fim
        ) ) THEN
            RAISE ex_data_sobreposta;
        END IF;
    END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN ex_data_sobreposta THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'datas sobrepõem épocas');
    WHEN ex_data_null THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'data fim não pode ser null');
END trgepocasnaosobrepostas;
/
```

Comment: Are you sure whether there is another Update trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is defined on the table `epoca`, and you're attempting to fetch from a cursor on the table `epoca` inside it. That's not allowed. Complex logic such as this doesn't belong in a trigger. I suggest you write a procedure to perform the updates and all this validation logic.

Comment: why does it work when inserting then, it should not work when i insert as  well right?